# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\ln{x}}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}(1+x)}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am having some difficulty with this exercise:

Calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\ln{x}}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}(1+x)}}\mathrm dx$$

By Wolfram Alpha, I know that the Answer is $\frac{-2}{3}\pi^2$. I tried to change variable $\arctan(\sqrt{x})=t$ cause I see (1+x), and it lead to $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\frac{\ln({\tan(t)})}{\tan(t)^{1/3}}}\mathrm dx$, and got stuck.

Can anyone help me solve this or give me some ideas.

Comment: Partial fractions then integrate by parts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be easily done using beta function.

Starting with the substitution $x\mapsto x^3$, we get
$$I = 9\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^3}\,\mathrm dx $$
Now, consider the integral
$$I (m,n)= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^m}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm dx $$
Using $x^n=t$,
$$\begin{align} I(m,n) &= \frac1n\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\frac{m+1}n-1}}{1+t}\,\mathrm dt \\ &= \frac1n \mathcal B\Big(\frac{m+1}n,1-\frac{m+1}n\Big)\\ &= \frac\pi n\csc \Big(\frac{\pi(m+1)}n\Big)\end{align}$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $m$,
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^m\ln x}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\csc \Big(\frac{\pi(m+1)}n\Big)\cot \Big(\frac{\pi(m+1)}n\Big)$$
Now, setting $(m,n)=(0,3)$ and multiplying by $9$, you will get the desired result.

Comment: oh, I understand !! One more Ques, how do you come up with the idea I(m,n) ? thank u

Comment: @Jaytone I have encountered a lot of such integrals. So, experience. BTW, if you are satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! Alternatively, you can avoid the substitution $x\mapsto x^3$ by noting that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln{x}}{x^{2/3}(1+x)}~dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-2/3}\ln{x}}{1+x}dx=\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\mu}}{1+x}~dx\Big|_{\mu=-2/3}.$$
and the last integral is just $B(-\mu,\mu+1)$.

Comment: @projectile that's also a good way to do it.

Comment: Very nice. I was not expecting such a general result.

Comment: @K.def Thanks a lot. 

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that does not rely on the use of special functions.  Rather, we make use of contour integration in the complex plane.  To this end, we proceed.

---

First, we have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^{2/3}(1+x)}\,dx=\left.\left(\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{t}}{1+x}\,dx\right)\right|_{\,t=-2/3}\tag 1$$

Let $f(z)=\frac{z^t}{(1+z)}$, $t\in(-1,0)$ and $C_{KH}$ denote the classical keyhole contour with the branch cut along the positive real axis.  Then, the residue theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_{KH}}f(z,t)\,dz&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(f(z,t), z=-1\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i e^{i\pi t}
\end{align}$$

Hence, we find by integrating around the keyhole contour that

$$\begin{align}
2\pi i e^{i\pi t}=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi t}x^t}{1+x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

from which we have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t}{1+x}\,dx=-\pi \csc(\pi t)$$

Diferentiating and setting $t=-2/3$ yields the coveted result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^{2/3}(1+x)}=-2\pi^2/3$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Very nice! :) There's also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810485/170231) contour-based solution that can be adapted here.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you!  We're using the same contour (i.e., the classical keyhole), but have augmented the integral differently.  Nice to see that analysis works. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $y=x^{1/3}$, fold up the integral at $y=1$, and exploit Taylor series:

$$\newcommand{\trilog}[1]{\psi^{(1)}\left(#1\right)}
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^{2/3} (1+x)} \, dx \\
&= 9 \int_0^\infty \frac{\log y}{1+y^3} \, dy \\
&= 9 \int_0^1 \frac{1-y}{1+y^3} \log y \, dy \\
&= 9 \sum_{n\ge0} (-1)^n \int_0^1 \left(y^{3n} - y^{3n+1}\right) \log y \, dy \\
&= 9 \sum_{n\ge0} (-1)^n \left(\frac1{(3n+2)^2} - \frac1{(3n+1)^2}\right) \\
&= 9 \sum_{n\ge0} \left[\left(\frac1{(3n+2)^2} - \frac1{(3n+1)^2}\right) - \left(\frac1{(3n+2)^2} - \frac1{(3n+1)^2}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac14 \left[\trilog{\frac13} + \trilog{\frac23} - \left(\trilog{\frac16} + \trilog{\frac56}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac14 \left(\frac{4\pi^2}3 - 4\pi^2\right) = \boxed{-\frac{2\pi^2}3}
\end{align*}$$

where $\psi^{(1)}$ denotes the trigamma function, and the penultimate step follows from its [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function#Recurrence_and_reflection_formulae).

Comment: Well done!  (+1) How do you like my solution?