# Calculate the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+8)}dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Calculate the integral using complex analysis
> $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+8)}dx$$

This integral can easily be calculated using integration by parts, but I was unable to solve it using residues... I don't know which pole should be and which direction

Could you please tell me how to solve this integral using residues?

Comment: What do you mean by using deductions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Well, that's called using residues. The word "deductions" doesn't even appear in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: If you want to solve it with residues, try to use the so called keyhole contour, or "Pacman" contour. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with "Pacman"

Comment: That's a pretty standard contour to work with when you have a function which requires choosing a branch. Take a look at example $2$ here: https://math.nyu.edu/~cerfon/complex1_notes/Lecture_9.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^{1/3} (x+8)} \, dx \stackrel{x\mapsto x^3}= 9 \int_0^\infty \frac{x \log x}{x^3+8} \, dx$$

Now consider the integral in $\Bbb C$,

$$J = \oint_\Gamma \frac{z \log^{\color{red}2}z}{z^3+8} \, dz$$

where $\Gamma$ is a keyhole contour like the one pictured in Wikipedia's [Example 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts), taking the branch cut along the positive real axis. The integrals along the larger and smaller circular arcs will vanish as their respective radii approach $\infty$ and $0$. As we approach the real axis from above, we have on the upper line segment that $\log z\to\log|z|$; from below, on the lower line segment, $\log z\to\log|z|+i2\pi$.

By the residue theorem,

$$J = i2\pi \sum \underset{z=\omega}{\operatorname{Res}} \frac{z\log^2z}{z^3+8} = \frac{4\pi^3}{3\sqrt3} - i \left(\frac{4\pi^3}{27} + \frac{4\pi^2}{3\sqrt3} \log2\right)$$

where $\omega^3=-8$.

Now, parameterizing the upper/lower line segments by $z=x\pm i\varepsilon$, respectively, we have

$$\begin{align*}
J &= \lim_{R\to\infty\\\varepsilon\to0^+} \int_\varepsilon^R \frac{(x+i\varepsilon) \log^2(x+i\varepsilon)}{(x+i\varepsilon)^3+8} \, dx + \int_R^\varepsilon \frac{(x-i\varepsilon) \left(\log(x-i\varepsilon) + i2\pi\right)^2}{(x-i\varepsilon)^3+8} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{x \log^2x}{x^3+8} \, dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{x \left(\log^2x + i4\pi \log x - 4\pi^2\right)}{x^3+8} \, dx \\
&= -i4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{x \log x}{x^3+8} \, dx + 4\pi^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+8} \, dx
\end{align*}$$

so that upon matching up the imaginary parts, we conclude

$$\frac19 I = \frac{\pi^2}{27} + \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}\log2$$

Answer (score 5):

I used Feymann's trick:
$$\text{Let}\quad f\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x}}{t+8}dt\quad\Rightarrow\quad f'\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(t\right)}{\sqrt[3]{t}\left(t+8\right)}dt$$
$$f(x)=-8^x\pi\csc(\pi x)\quad\Rightarrow\quad f'\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3} (\pi + \sqrt{3} \ln(8))$$

I don't know what you mean by "deductions" but this is a much faster method than integration by parts

Comment: I mixed up the words. That's what I meant. Could you show the second way through the Residue?

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)

Answer (score 3):

We seek to evaluate

$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-1/3}}{x+8} \log x \; dx.$$

We introduce the function

$$F(z) = \frac{\exp(-1/3\times \mathrm{Log}(z))}{z+8}
\mathrm{Log}(z)$$

where the logarithm has the branch cut on the positive real axis and
$0\le \mathrm{arg} \; \mathrm{Log} \lt 2\pi.$

We now use a keyhole contour to  integrate $F(z)$ with the slot on the
positive real axis  (note that the pole  at $z=-8$ is not  on the cut)
and the large circle of radius  $R$ while the circle around the origin
has  radius $\varepsilon$.  We  have on  the  large circle  $\Gamma_1$
(number segments in counterclockwise fashion)

$$\frac{\exp(-1/3 \times \mathrm{Log}(R \exp(i\theta)))}
{R\exp(i\theta) + 8} \mathrm{Log}(R\exp(i\theta)).$$

Computing the norm we find $2\pi R \times \frac{R^{-1/3}}{R} \log R
\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty.$  (Remember that $|\exp(-1/3\times
i\theta)|=1.$)

Similarly for the small circle $\Gamma_3$ we have

$$\frac{\exp(-1/3 \times \mathrm{Log}(\varepsilon \exp(i\theta)))}
{\varepsilon \exp(i\theta) + 8} 
\mathrm{Log}(\varepsilon\exp(i\theta)).$$

Compute the norm once more to get $2\pi\varepsilon \times 
\frac{\varepsilon^{-1/3}}{8} \log\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ as
$\varepsilon\rightarrow 0.$

Now we get the integral $J$ on the line $\Gamma_0$ just above the
slot and below the slot on $\Gamma_2$  we find

$$\int_{\Gamma_2} 
\frac{\exp(-1/3\times \log (z) - 1/3 \times 2\pi i )}{z+8}
(\log(z) + 2\pi i) \; dz
\\ = - \exp(-2\pi i/3) J  
- 2\pi i \exp(-2\pi i/3) \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-1/3}}{x+8} \; dx
\\ = - \exp(-2\pi i/3) J  - 2\pi i \exp(-2\pi i/3) K.$$

Now to compute $K$ we use the same keyhole contour and get for the
circular bounds $2\pi R \frac{R^{-1/3}}{R} \rightarrow 0$ as
$R\rightarrow\infty$ as well as $2\pi\varepsilon \frac{1}{8} 
\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{1/3}} \rightarrow 0$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 
0.$ It follows by the Cauchy Residue Theorem that

$$K (1-\exp(-2\pi i/3)) =
2\pi i \; \underset{z=-8}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{z^{-1/3}}{z+8} 
= 2\pi i \times (-8)^{-1/3}
\\ = 2\pi i \times \exp(-1/3 \times \mathrm{Log}(-8))
\\ = 2\pi i \times \frac{1}{2} \times \exp( -1/3 \times \pi i)
\\ = \pi i \exp( -1/3 \times \pi i).$$

We obtain for $K$

$$K = \pi i \frac{\exp(-\pi i/3)}
{1-\exp(-2\pi i/3)}
\\ = \pi i \frac{1}{\exp(\pi i/3) - \exp(-\pi i/3)}
= \frac{\pi}{2 \sin(\pi/3)}
= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \pi.$$

We thus obtain for $J$

$$J (1-\exp(-2\pi i/3))
- 2\pi i \times \exp(-2\pi i/3) \pi \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
\\ = 2\pi i \times  \; \underset{z=-8}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{z^{-1/3}}{z+8} \;\mathrm{Log}(z).$$

The residue works out to

$$\frac{1}{2} \exp(-1/3\times \pi i)
(3\log(2) + \pi i).$$

Substituting

$$J (1-\exp(-2\pi i/3))
\\ = 2\pi i \times \exp(-2\pi i/3) \pi \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
+ \pi i \exp(-\pi i/3) (3\log 2 + \pi i).$$

Continuing,

$$J (\exp(\pi i/3)-\exp(-\pi i/3))
\\ = 2\pi i \times \exp(-\pi i/3) \pi \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
+ \pi i (3\log 2 + \pi i)$$

or

$$J \sin(\pi/3)
= \pi \times \exp(-\pi i/3) \pi \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
+ \frac{1}{2} \pi (3\log 2 + \pi i).$$

Now we know $J$ must be a real number so we may omit the imaginary
components on the right to get

$$J \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
= \pi \times \cos(\pi/3) \pi \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
+ \frac{3}{2} \pi \log 2.$$

We have at last

$$J
= \pi \times \pi \frac{1}{3}
+ \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} \pi \log 2$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{3} \pi^2 + \pi \sqrt{3} \log 2.}$$